# Mediaplayer doesn't work.plese help me

Tags: android, media

I have a question
I want to play a music that user choose it. this is my code

```
    Button butt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    butt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 10);
        }
    });

}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == 10) {
        Uri uriSound = data.getData();
        play(this, uriSound);
    }
}

    private void play(Context context, Uri uri) {

        try {
            MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
            mp.setDataSource(context, uri);
            mp.start();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SecurityException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

But when I choose music, it doesn't work in my activity. I am beginner in android please help me

Comment: which error are you getting?

Comment: I don't get error but when I choose music from my sd card it doesn't play in my activity. I have a book that I want to play a music in all activities of my book

Answer (score 0):

Use below code It will work

```
Intent intent = new Intent();  
intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);  
File file = new File(YOUR_SONG_URI);  
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "audio/*");  
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: I want my app plays musics that users like. Maybe they want to play different musics in different path

Comment: You can always define URI

Comment: Can you help me by a example. I don't understand